# Negative weight graph edges?

Tags: graph

We all have seen graphs with edge weight where the weight may represent anything from
lengths, costs, etc ...,  but what does a negative weight edge stand for ?
e.g lengths my apply to road lengths in real world, is there a similar analogy for negative weight ?
Thanx

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: +1 Good question, wrong site. I'd recommend migrating this to math SE or similar

Comment: An edge with negative weight `−w` is interpreted as a resistance of `(1/w)` in series with a “`inverting amplifier`”, denoted as (−) in the graph.I had the same query...

Comment: This is programming related. In exactly the same way that 'what is a vector for?' is programming related.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Imagine that your graph is tracking the molecules that are consumed and produced in a chemical reaction and the edge weights represent the energy produced in the transition. A negative edge weight would be a transition that needs energy to be achieved (for example splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen).